# Pandas change value based on other column values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the value of each item in the column 'ageatbirth' to '1' if the 'race' is 2.
In pseudocode:

```
If 'race' == 2 and 'ageatbirth' == 2:

'ageatbirth' == 1
```

Is there an easy way to do this for a very large dataset?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
m = df['race'].eq(2) & df['ageatbirth'].eq(2)

df['ageatbirth'] = df['ageatbirth'].mask(m, 1)
# or
df.loc[m, 'ageatbirth'] = 1
```